How do you create a Strong Name Key file for a .NET8 Console project in Visual Studio 2022?
In my C# .NET 4.6.2 project the GUI provides a mechanism for me to create a strong name key file:

But, now I am trying to create a .NET8 console application and the GUI is different:

There is no mechanism for creating a new strong name key file. So how do I go about doing this?
